# The class was not found in the chain configured namespaces

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony5

**Hello, i need to explain what i'm was doing at first:**

- I was on a project and for some reason I ended up having to use **two databases** instead of just one. so i do what it was needed to do, i change my doctrine.yaml settings with what is explain in the symfony doc and in that moment the error appeared

An SQL error that says that it was **no column found** for X request on X table

- (the error is SQLSTATE[42S02], but it's not important)

(in parallel of that error i need to say that the "--em" shit didn't work for me when i do  `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff/migrate --em=default or customer` so i does indeed  `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --em=default or customer`  and i don't know why ! so if you have something to say here i'll take it too.)

Anyway i go back to what i was explaining,
This sql error appear because of my controller, they working with default Repository implementation (`MyClassNameRepository $myClasNameReposiotry` for an exemple) that was normaly implement the default EntityManager but it doesn't and that throw this error.

At this point i though that i had an error in some files in symfony because of a shit i probably does. I don't have the time for replacing all the repository implementation, soo i create a new project with the doctrine config that is needed for working with two database according to the symfony doc. Is the same as the One in my project :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
            customer:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_CUSTOMER_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    Main:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: Main
            customer:
                connection: customer
                mappings:
                    Customer:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Customer'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Customer'
                        alias: Customer
```

That is the same config than the one in symfony doc except for the Main dir.
i created my entities, one in each database and i does a crud on them.

**The Hierarchy files:**

```
src/
-----Entity/
     ----Product
     ----Customer/
            -ProductCustomer
-----Repository/
     ----ProductRepository
     ----Customer/
         -----ProductCustomerRepository
And same for the form
```

And with this testApplication i saw a new error, for the customer part i had the same sql error, because the column was searched in the wrong bdd, after changing the code for :

**this**

```
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="customer_produit_customer_index", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(ProductCustomerRepository $productCustomerRepository): Response
    {
        return $this->render('customer/produit_customer/index.html.twig', [
            'produit_customers' => $productCustomerRepository->findAll(),
        ]);
    }
```

**to this**

```
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="customer_produit_customer_index", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $productCustomers = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(ProduitCustomerRepository::class, "customer")
            ->findAll()
        ;
        return $this->render('customer/produit_customer/index.html.twig', [
            'produit_customers' => $productCustomers,
        ]);
    }
```

The error has changed, as I expected and know i have :

```
The class 'App\Repository\Customer\ProduitCustomerRepository' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity\Customer
```

No matter how much I search the internet, I can't find anything that really solves my mistakes. Now I'm tired of looking, especially since I don't understand these errors because it's not the first time I've set up an application connected to two databases, but it's the first time that I have these errors.

So please help me =D.

Comment: I forgot the ```default_entity_manager: 'default' ``` in the orm for the doctrine.yaml file when i copy past.

Comment: But beware, this is not what causes the error!

Comment: Okay yesterday i was really tired, and know i can see that i do shit in my controller, i implement the wrong class in 'getRepository' he need the Entity and i gave him the Repository, so i change that and know i'm back to theSQL error, because the column is still searched in the wrong bdd

Comment: I need a solution please, for the SQL error 'SQLSTATE[42S02] table not found'

Comment: Apparently it's all because i tried to implement two entity manager while a part of my entities was not in a child directory, like 'Customer'
What has to do it's to move the controller that are in the racine of App\Entity into a child directory like App\Entity\Main ...It's annoying because in the documentation it does not explicitly say that we cannot do as I wanted to do the thing.