# Symfony SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I have an error that i don't understand, few days ago i create a **new project** for trying resolving this error in a project with fewer files and **i solve it, but** the solution didn't work in my Real project.
( This error is related to an **other question** i asked few day ago : [The class was not found in the chain configured namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64594642/the-class-was-not-found-in-the-chain-configured-namespaces), but like i said i solve it so maybe i need to ask a new question ).

I tried to implement two EntityManager in my project for **multple database connexion**,
and that is the problem, oneof my entityManager searched tables in the wrong place, and don't find theme ... IDK why and most crazy thing it's some function work and other didn't, you'll see that :

In first my doctrine.yaml file :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
            customer:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_CUSTOMER_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    Tdsmo:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Tdsmo'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Tdsmo'
                        alias: Tdsmo
            customer:
                connection: customer
                mappings:
                    Customer:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Customer'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Customer'
                        alias: Customer
```

And know an exemple of some function that i can use in my controller :

```
        // this one work, but his not the default connexion ..
        // return all agent in agentCustomer that is in the second database.
        $agentCustomers = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(AgentCustomer::class, "customer")
            ->findAll()
        ;

        // And this one, that is the default connexion, didn't work like this same for 'AgentRepository $agentRepository' that can be implemented in the method and called after for ->findAll()
        // return an error
        $agents = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Agent::class, "default")
            ->findAll()
        ;
```

**BUT** This shit work and return a array with all column and values :

```
        $connexion = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection('default')
        $agentsFetch = $connexion->fetchAll("SELECT * from agent");
```

But i can't use the fetch method 'cause if i do in my template i need to replace all *agent.firstName* by *agent.first_name* for example, Furthermore i **need to understand** why one method work but not the other ...

Finally, the full error is :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.email AS email_2, t0.roles AS roles_3, t0.password AS password_4, t0.firstName AS firstName_5, t0.lastName AS lastName_6, t0.registeredAt AS registeredAt_7, t0.telephone AS telephone_8, t0.fonction_id AS fonction_id_9, t0.subdivision_id AS subdivision_id_10, t0.section_id AS section_id_11 FROM Agent t0':

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 't0.firstName' inconnu dans field list
```

**Thank you for your help !**

Comment: Is the `firstName` property of the `Agent` class correctly mapped to the `first_name` column of the `agent` table and does this column exist in the table? Show us your mapping configuration (property annotations for `firstName`) for the `Agent` class, please. Clear your cache to avoid issues of outdated doctine mappings, too.

Comment: everything worked before i start to work with an other database, but yeah it seems to be that, i do a `php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate --em=EachDatabase ` and i see that i had an error for the 'default' databse, the schema was not in sync with the correct current mapping file.
So thank you for that, BUT now when in my template i do something like `agent.firstName` it return nothing : ""
and if i do a dump of my agents i can see that I collect them all ..

Comment: okay that's what the columns were emptied .. And when i add a firstName and a lastName like that is supposed to be, i have again the error, because now the dataabse schema is not anymore in sync with the mapping file

Answer (score 1):

**OKAY**

Thanks to **Nicolai**, he help me found the real problem, it was because of the **naming strategy** !

I don't know why but if it is not explicitly defined in the context of the use of several entityManager doctrine will generate the tables in the database in **camelCase**, instead of the **snake_case** (underscore).In any case that's what was causing me problem

So it must be specified with this line :

```
naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
```

**For where i found to specify **'underscore'** :**

[How to configure naming strategy in Doctrine 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702657/how-to-configure-naming-strategy-in-doctrine-2)

**And the doc For thoses who want :**

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineBundle/configuration.html#configuration-overview